# How to calculate with angular and php?

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm building a project with angular and php. I have a "Stock" table in my database, and I can retrieve all data in a table. I want to calculate  total "Quantity" column and display total but I have no idea what to do. can anyone please help?

php :

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hamatkin');

  mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_client = utf8");
  mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_connection = utf8");
  mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_results = utf8");

  if(!$connection){
    die("couldnt connect".mysqli_error);
  }

  $query="SELECT `stock_id`,`product_name`,`description`,`quantity` FROM `stock`";
  $queryResult = $connection->query($query);
  $queryResult2 = array();
  if( $queryResult->num_rows>0){
    while($row = $queryResult->fetch_assoc()){
      $queryResult2[] = $row;
    }
  }
  $queryResult3 = json_encode($queryResult2);
   echo json_encode($queryResult3);
?>
```

HTML:

```
    </div>

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table  class="customer-list table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <!-- <th>#</th> -->
          <th class="Column-Header">קוד מוצר</th>
          <th class="Column-Header">שם מוצר</th>
          <th class="Column-Header">תיאור מוצר</th>
          <!-- <th class="Column-Header">כמות במלאי</th>
          <th class="Column-Header">סה"כ</th> -->


        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in stockReport" ng-init="setTotals(item)">
              <td>{{item.ProductName}}</td>
              <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
          </tr>

      <tfoot>
          <tr class="bg-warning">
              <td>Totals</td>
              <td>{{invoiceCount}}</td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>

        </tfoot>


      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
```

Controller:

```
"use strict";
angular.module('dataSystem').controller('reportsCtrl', function ($scope, $route, $location, $http) {
  $http({method:'GET', url:'api/reports-tab/stock-report.php/'})
      .then(function(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data));
        $scope.v = arr;


      })

      // This will log you the error code and trace, if there is an error.

      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('err', err)
      });


      $scope.setTotals = function(item){
          if (item){
              item.total = item.quantity * item.unitCost;
              $scope.invoiceCount += item.quantity;

          }
      }



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a function in JS as below,

**JS:**

```
$scope.setTotals = function(item){
        if (item){
            item.total = item.quantity * item.unitCost;
            $scope.invoiceCount += item.quantity;

        }
    }
```

**View**

```
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="setTotals(item)">
            <td>{{item.ProductName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>                 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr class="bg-warning">
            <td>Totals</td>
            <td>{{invoiceCount}}</td>
            <td></td>                   
        </tr>
```

[`Working App`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/ocm8r25e/2/)

Comment: can you please check?

Comment: No your html code is not correct, can you create a plunker link

Comment: @tanyaa Check the updated plunker with your HTML. http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/ocm8r25e/2/